# ActiveMQ: Simple topic based cluster

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel

Well, lets say I'm building ActiveMQ based chat application. It's pretty simple. Having only one `QUEUE.IN` and one `TOPIC.OUT`. All messages are simply routed right away from `QUEUE.IN` to `TOPIC.OUT`. Clients are producing their chat messages to `QUEUE.IN` and consuming from `TOPIC.OUT`.  That's all.

Now, I wanna cluster it. Don't need something complex. Just run few other identical nodes `(A..N)`. Basically, client, subscribed to `A` node, sends message to `A.QUEUE.IN`. This message must then appear on all other nodes `(A..N).TOPIC.OUT`. This could be easily done by simple camel route that re-route all messages comes to `TOPIC.OUT` to other nodes, but is there some nice ActiveMQ-native way to do so? Like some queue/topic shared among several AMQ instances?

Comment: could you explain first why you would name the Queue differently on each node ?

ActiveMQ Can easily be clustered so the queue QUEUE.IN exists on all the different nodes.. Activemq will then distribute the messages to the correct consumers on the same node OR a different node.. , you can keep the same logic with the routing..

However, since i am asking questions anyways: why would you produce on a queue and then simply route them to a topic ? You can easily just make your clients produce on the topic in the first place. It saves you some overhead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can find your answer here:

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-distributed-queues-work.html

Answer (score 0):

You can forward messages to multiple endpoints in activemq using virtual destinations.

http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html